# UITableView Subclass method not calling

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, subclass

I've created a class called "ParseMessages" which is a subclass of UITableView. In the StoryBoard, I've added a UITableView and changed the class to "ParseMessages".

In the ViewDidLoad method of the ViewController containing the UITableView, I'm trying to call one of the "ParseMessages" class methods - there isn't a crash, but the function never executed.

**ParseMessages Class (.m)**

```
- (void)setupMessageTableViewWithThread:(Thread *)thread {
    NSLog(@"function working!");
}
```

**ViewController containing UITableView (ParseMessages)**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet ParseMessages *table_view;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    Thread *tempthread = [[Thread alloc] init];
    tempthread.threadid = @"82";
    [self.table_view setupMessageTableViewWithThread:tempthread];

}
```

Suggestions anyone?

Comment: Is `IBOutlet ParseMessages *table_view;` connected to your table view?

Comment: How did I not check this *sigh* thank you! What do I do with this question now as it's answered?

Comment: You can remove the question or answer it with the solution so other people with the same problem may see it :)

Comment: Lovely, thanks mate! :)

Comment: In seven years of professionally developing for iOS I have never seen a need to subclass UITableView. Why are you doing that?

Comment: Clutter reduction and to let the subclass handle everything rather than the ViewController

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @vitormm - the "ParseMessages" outlet wasn't connected to the StoryBoard object. I simply connected them together and the code ran perfectly!